# Are + plural noun or singular?

Tags: verbs, adverbs

It sounds correct to me to say.

> She is actually a man.
>   (Regardless how weird the sentence is)

But in this situation as we take plural subject.

> they are actually surprises.

It sounds a bit odd like I am using the adverb to modify the noun (surprises), although it's intended for the verb to be.

Can we say

> they are actually a surprise.

Is there any rule that explains what should we use after plural subject + to be, singular noun or it has to be plural? or we can use both, and is this sentence *they are actually surprises* correct?

And what is the official term of this Noun/prounoun + to be + noun
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can say that, and all your examples are fine. There's no rule that says the predicative complement and the predicand must always agree (though they usually do). There are plenty of perfectly acceptable examples to be found, for example: _Our neighbours are a nuisance_; _The accidents were the result of a power failure_.

Comment: There's no such thing as subject-complement agreement. Only a verb has to agree with the subject.

Comment: That's not strictly true. Most people would find examples like _My daughters are a doctor_ and _The person who complained was my parents_ quite unacceptable.